# Show array element - when index is a variable - inaccesible value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

during debbugging,
why I can't view an array element?
when index is a variable (`arrai[i]`) I get Inaccesible value issue
But when index is a const number (`array[1]`) it works fine.
Please view my picture:

[image]

I get the issue with any type of array (simple array of integers or strings or also with multidimensional array of objects)

I use Delphi XE4

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure optimization is disabled for your project when in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Optimization in the Project Options when run in DEBUG mode.

Comment: Tested with Delphi 10.4.1. When optimization option is TRUE, then weekdays[i] is not accessible during debug. But it gives a clear message now: "Variable 'i' inaccessible here due to optimization".